# Identificar elemento entre un numero indeterminado de elementos con el mismo id con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, id

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Tengo una cuadricula de divs los cuales tienen una imagen varias etiquetas y demás, cada div tiene un botón - y + en el centro un input, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando de clic en el botón + o en el botón -, aumento o disminuya 1 pero solo en el input donde del div donde se presionaron los botones

este es el código de lo botones

```
<div class="item-botons">
    <label for="">$ '.$precio.'</label>
    <button id="btnmas">+</button>
    <input type="text" name="" id="valorinput" value="1">
    <button id="btnmenos">-</button>
    <label for="">%10</label>
    <button style = "width:auto; height: auto; padding:5px">Agregar</button>
</div>
```

> que función podría utilizar o de que manera puedo hacer que sea posible?

Comment: El atributo `id` ha de ser único, en caso contrario el HTML es incorrecto. La solución es generar un ID distinto para cada botón o usar `btnmas` como valor del atributo `class`.

Answer (score 3):

debes tener en cuenta que el atributo id de un elemento debe ser único, por lo que si tienes varios inputs, no deberían tener todos el id="valorInput".
Para hacer lo que pides, yo le daría a los inputs una clase y crearía una función que recibiese el botón y buscar el input relacionado:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Creo una función que sirva para los dos botones, simplemente cambiará la cantidad pasada
function sumar(boton, cantidad){
    //Cojo el padre del botón, que es el div
    var parent = boton.parentElement;
    //Busco un hijo del div con la clase valorInput y seleccione el primer elemento
    var input = parent.getElementsByClassName( 'valorInput' )[0];
    var valorActual = input.value + cantidad;
    input.value = valorActual;
}
</script>
<div class="item-botons">
    <label for="">$ '.$precio.'</label>
    <button id="btnmas" onclick="sumar(this,1)">+</button>
    <input type="text" name="" class="valorinput" value="1">
    <button id="btnmenos" onclick="sumar(this, -1)">-</button>
    <label for="">%10</label>
    <button style = "width:auto; height: auto; padding:5px">Agregar</button>
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.

Comment: Personalmente no me gusta usar "inline events", pero es una opción totalmente válida. En mi respuesta he usado otra opción similar.

Comment: A mi tampoco me gusta, pero como en la pregunta no dejan claro hasta donde conocen de javascript, he usado inline events por parecerme más fácil de entender. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

Si asumimos que usas clases en lugar de ID para encontrar los elementos, podrías hacer algo así:

```js
let botonesMas = document.querySelectorAll('.btnmas');

function onClick(evento) {
  let siblings =Array.from( evento.target.parentNode.childNodes);
  debugger;
  let input = siblings.find(elem => elem.classList && elem.classList.contains('valorinput'));
  input.value = +input.value + 1;
}

botonesMas.forEach(boton => {
  boton.addEventListener('click',onClick);
})
```

```html
<div class="item-botons">
    <button class="btnmas">+</button>
    <input type="text" name="" class="valorinput" value="1">
    <button class="btnmenos">-</button>
</div>

<div class="item-botons">
    <button class="btnmas">+</button>
    <input type="text" name="" class="valorinput" value="1">
    <button class="btnmenos">-</button>
</div>

<div class="item-botons">
    <button class="btnmas">+</button>
    <input type="text" name="" class="valorinput" value="1">
    <button class="btnmenos">-</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola aca va un ejemplo con los comentarios explicativos en el codigo:

```
    //Obtengo todos los div que contienen la clase item-bottons.
    var els = document.querySelectorAll(".item-botons");
    //Recorro todos los div encontrados.
    els.forEach(function(el) {
        //El primer boton del div es el que suma. Registro el evento asociado.    
        el.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
            //Actualiza sumando 1 por cada click   
            updateValue(this, +1);
        });
        //El segundo boton del div es el que resta. Registro el evento asociado.
        el.getElementsByTagName("button")[1].addEventListener("click", function () {
           //Actualiza restando 1 por cada click   
            updateValue(this, -1);
        });
    });
    
    //Esta funcion actualiza en el input text.
    function updateValue(obj, value) {
        //t es el control input text.
        var t = obj.parentNode.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']")[0];
        //Si el valor actual esta vacio o si no es entero le asigno valor 1:
        if (t.value.length === 0 || !t.value.match(/^\d+$/)) {
            t.value = 1;
        } else {
           //Tomo el valor actual y lo convierto a tipo entero y le paso el +1 o -1
            var currentValue = parseInt(t.value, 10) + value;
            if (currentValue < 1) {
               //si es menor < 1 lo actualizo a 1 para prevenir valores < 1.
                currentValue = 1;
            }
            //y por ultimo actualizo el nuevo valor al input text.
            t.value = currentValue;
        }
    }
```

HTML EXAMPLE:

```
 <div class="item-botons">
            <button>+</button>
            <input type="text" name="" class="valorinput" value="1">
            <button>-</button>
            <button style = "width:auto; height: auto; padding:5px">Agregar</button>
        </div>
 <div class="item-botons">
            <button>+</button>
            <input type="text" name="" class="valorinput" value="1">
            <button>-</button>
            <button style = "width:auto; height: auto; padding:5px">Agregar</button>
        </div>
 <div class="item-botons">
            <button>+</button>
            <input type="text" name="" class="valorinput" value="1">
            <button>-</button>
            <button style = "width:auto; height: auto; padding:5px">Agregar</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta parece bien encaminada y los comentarios son claros, para hacerla aún mejor, estaría bien que pongas el HTML, para saber si hay cambios y, de preferencia, poner todo en un [Fragmento de código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1448/uso-de-fragmentos-o-bloques-de-c%C3%B3digo-ejecutable-code-snippet-cuando-respondem#1450) para que se pueda probar el funcionamiento aquí mismo.